# Form does not send data to database

Tags: symfony

I am new in Symfony and I have read almost all posts regarding sending data to database. I have included all the answers/solutions but still does not send to db.
Can someone please help?

> I have create a form and I want to send all the values in my database, I have also created the entity with class "Profile"

```
public function createProfile(Request $request)
{

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $profile = new Profile();

        $profile->setUserName('Name');
        $profile->setUserPosition('Position');
        $profile->setUserPhone('Phone');   
        $profile->setUserEmail('E-mail');   
        $profile->setUserDepartment('Department');



    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($profile)
        ->add('userName', TextType::class)
        ->add('userDepartment', ChoiceType::class, array(
             'placeholder' => 'Select department',
                'choices' => array(
                    'HR' => 'hr',
                    'Marketing' => 'marketing',
                    'Development' => 'development',
                    'Finance'   => 'finance',
                    'Logistics' => 'logistics',
                ),
        )) 
        ->add('userPosition', TextType::class)
        ->add('userPhone', TextType::class)
        ->add('userEmail', TextType::class)
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Create Profile'))
        ->getForm();


     $form->handleRequest($request);

     // the if statement does not work :(
     if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())  {

        dump($profile); // this doesn't return
        $form->bind($request);

        $form['userName']->getData();
        $form['userDepartment']->getData();
        $form['userPosition']->getData();
        $form['userPhone']->getData();
        $form['userEmail']->getData();

        $em->persist($profile);
        $em->flush();

    }

    return $this->render('dashboard/new_profile.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

//new_profile.html.twig

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_label(form.userName, 'Name') }}

{{ form_widget(form.userName, {'attr': {'placeholder': 'Your name', 'value':''} }) }}

{{ form_label(form.userPosition, 'Position') }}
{{ form_widget(form.userPosition, {'attr': {'placeholder': 'Your position', 'value':''} }) }}

{{ form_label(form.userPhone, 'Phone') }}
{{ form_widget(form.userPhone, {'attr': {'placeholder': 'Your phone', 'value':''} }) }}

{{ form_label(form.userEmail, 'E-mail') }}
{{ form_widget(form.userEmail, {'attr': {'placeholder': 'Your e-mail', 'value':''} }) }}

{{ form_label(form.userDepartment, 'Department') }}
{{ form_widget(form.userDepartment, {'attr': {'placeholder': 'Your department', 'value':''} }) }}

{{ form_rest(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Comment: Are you sure there are no validation errors? in should show in "validator" section in the profiler. You should also check which statement returns false is it `isSubmitted()` or `isValid()`?

Comment: @IwanWijaya how can I check that?

Comment: dump($form->isSubmitted()); 
dump($form->isValid());

Or use a debugger.

Comment: @IwanWijaya isSubmited() returns false and isValid() gives me this error "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Cannot check if an unsubmitted form is valid. Call Form::isSubmitted() before Form::isValid().")."

Comment: Go to `http://yoururl/_profiler` this will print you the debugger of Symfony. You can debug each request to your application. Take a look at form and validation section :)

Comment: @Mcsky I know that, there I see debug messages :)

Comment: So what is the error on your form, which fields ? `isValid` can't return you this error, it's the `render` method that throw you this exception

Comment: @Mcsky I have noticed that my form returns the method GET even if the form has the method post so I have find a related post with this issue and changed my twig with this {{ render(controller('App\\Controller\\DashboardController::createProfile' , {'request': app.request} )) }} and now I have another error "Attempted to call an undefined method named "bind" of class "Symfony\Component\Form\Form". at this line $form->bind($request);"

Comment: There is no need to call `bind` method. All the job to hydrate your entity from the data received in the request is do in the `handleRequest` :) You can put a dump before and after and you'll see your entity data change

Comment: @Mcsky I have made dump($form) and the result was:
  -config: FormBuilder {#5162 ▶}
  -parent: null
  -children: OrderedHashMap {#5171 ▶}
  -errors: []
  -submitted: false
  -clickedButton: null
  -modelData: Profile {#4193 ▶}
  -normData: Profile {#4193 ▶}
  -viewData: Profile {#4193 ▶}
  -extraData: []
  -transformationFailure: null
  -defaultDataSet: true
  -lockSetData: false

Comment: How are you trying to submit this form? Maybe there is an error in your twig?

Comment: @iiirxs I don't have any buttons in twig, my form is created from my controller!

Comment: So let me understand this: you are creating a form in controller but you don't want to use it in your twig?

Comment: few notes: your form should be created here: `src/Form`. Second - you manually set the form data - why are you using a form? Thirdly - you're not setting any profile data via the form.. so why would it go into the db?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs I expect all those notes because I am a newbie.How do I set the profile data via form?And how can I return the form if I don't create a twig and use "return $this->render('dashboard/new_profile.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));"

Comment: @Alex you should be able to just set the form to the matching field name - unless it's something special (like a MultiToMulti relationship field) you shoudn't have to manually set the data, just persist the object and flush

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs can you please show me a correct version of how my code should look so I can understand better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you should break up your code. You're controller file should **control** what happens - not do and build everything.

Build your form under the `Src/Form` directory. Create a new folder called Profile and create a file under that called AddType.php - full path should be `Src/Form/Profile/AddType.php`.

```
# Src/Form/Profile/AddType.php

<?php
    namespace App\Form\Profile;

    use App\Entity\Profile;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;

    class AddType extends AbstractType
    {
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder->add('userName', TextType::class)
                ->add('userDepartment', ChoiceType::class, array(
                    'placeholder' => 'Select department',
                    'choices' => array(
                        'HR' => 'hr',
                        'Marketing' => 'marketing',
                        'Development' => 'development',
                        'Finance'   => 'finance',
                        'Logistics' => 'logistics',
                    ),
                ))
                ->add('userPosition', TextType::class)
                ->add('userPhone', TextType::class)
                ->add('userEmail', TextType::class)
                ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Create Profile'));
        }

        public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
        {
            $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class' => Profile::class
            ));
        }
    }
```

Then in your controller:

```
<?php
    class CreateController extends Controller
    {
        public function index(Request $request)
        {
            $profile = new Profile();

            $form = $this->createForm(AddType::class, $profile);
            $form->handleRequest($request);

            if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

                $em->persist($profile);
                $em->flush();
                # what other actions you need. e.g redirect to success page
            }

            return $this->render('product/add.html.twig', ['form' => $form->createView()]);
        }
    }
```

Then render the form in your twig:

```
# templates/product/add.html.twig

{{ form_start(form) }}
    {# your custom code for rendering the form #} 
    {# if you leave default then it should render with bad styles etc. #}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

**Note:** You may have to change above code to suit your coding needs but should (in theory) work - this works from a page generated with a twig file - you shouldn't have a form in a controller if you don't plan to use a form. Just pass the data in manually ...